# How does "Max Angle" work when using Tris to Quads?

Tags: modeling

According to [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces#Convert_Triangles_to_Quads):

> This value (between 0 and 180) controls the threshold for
>   this tool to work on adjacent triangles. With a threshold of 0.0, it
>   will only join adjacent triangles that form a perfect rectangle (i.e.
>   right-angled triangles sharing their hypotenuses). Larger values are
>   required for triangles with a shared edge that is small, relative to
>   the size of the other edges of the triangles.

However, I don't quite follow that part (even trying my best to), and still puzzling on how it works exactly.

Can anyone explain more about it, for easier understanding?

[image]

**P.S.: I know what it is for, just can hardly understand how it works from Wiki.**

Comment: Hi, it has 'max face angle' and 'max shape angle' now, 'max face angle' is the angle between tris. what about 'max shape angle'?

Answer (score 1):

An overly simple answer is that a higher value means it will be more likely to form quads. A lesser value will be less likely to make triangles into quads. If you sculpt something with dynamic topology and then try the tool it will explain itself pretty quickly.